# Pass array from php back to javascript and loop over it

Tags: php, ajax, json

Hi I'm working on passing back an array from php to javascript. I learned online that I should use json_encode on the array when passing it back but now that i have it in the ajax i'm unsure how i can loop over it because doing things like `response[0]` gives me `[` and `response[1]` gives me `"` although when writing the entire thing to the document using innerHTML i can see it looks like an array but using a for loop gives me each letter like i stated above with the `response[0]` equaling [ rather than the first entry. What am i doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

**PHP**

```
<?PHP
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    mysql_select_db("Colleges");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Colleges` ORDER BY School");
    $schools = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($schools, $row['School']);
    }
    mysql_close();
    die(json_encode($schools));
?>
```

**Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function schools(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "Schools.php",
                type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                //Loop over response
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decode your JSON response (which is a string actually) to be able to work with it as with an object:

```
var respObj = JSON.parse(response);
```

The other way around is noticing jQuery that JSON will be supplied by the server (with either `dataType: 'json'` ajax parameter or `Content-Type: application/json` response header).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
for ( variable in response ) {
    alert(results[variable]);
}
```

---

JQuery

```
$.each(response, function(ind, val){
   alert("index:" + ind + ". value:" + val);
});
```

Comment: `response` supposed to be an array; and it's not recommended to loop through arrays with `for-in`. With jQuery, rather good `$.each` method is available; without, old crusty `for (var i = 0, l < arr.length; i < l; i++) { ... }` idiom is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

In the object you pass to the `ajax` method, you should try to add `dataType: 'json'` in order to specify that the result is json, or you could specify it in your php script calling `header('Content-type: application/json');` before the call to `die();`

Doing so will result in your `response` being the object you expect instead of a string.

Finally, you could leave it as is, and call in your success callback `response = $.parseJSON(response);` which will take the response string and turn it into an object, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Following if it helps

 res=jQuery.parseJSON(response);

for(i=0;i<res.length;i++)
{
  alert(res[i].propertyname);

}
```

here property name implies to the keys on json .In your case it can be 'School' or just a number i or value  can also be just res[i]